# Bash function that breaks loop

Tags: linux, bash, function, loops, break

I made a `bash` `function` that looks something like this:

```
keystroke()
{
    read -s -n1 -t0.1 key     #Read a single keystroke for 0.1 seconds
    [ "$key" = $'\e' ] &&     #If the pressed key is escape
    {
        echo Aborted by user  #Display message
        break                 #Break parent loop
    }
}
```

And whenever I needed to gracefully end a `loop` in other `bash` functions, i just called keystroke. I am no longer able to do this since `bash` v4.4.0 says:

```
-bash: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

How can I solve this without copying the same code over and over again more than 10x?

Comment: Return a status code that is checked by the caller of the function?

Comment: I don't see any loop in your code. Mb that's why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For functions you should use `return`:

```
keystroke() {
    ...
    return
}
```

Optionally add an integer (between 0 and 127) as the return value e.g.:

```
keystroke() {
    ...
    return 1
}
```

Note that, otherwise the exit status of the last command will be used as the return value.

Comment: I guess I could go that way, although in my simplified example I forgot to mention keystroke function forwards the exit status of whatever executes before it.

Comment: It does not really answer the question. The question is "How to write a function that will break its upper/parent loop?". Apparently in previous Bash versions, `break` was working in functions, and in Bash >=4.4 it's not. The first comment was a good answer: "Return a status code that is checked by the caller of the function". I guess there is no other way now: `while true; do keystroke && break; ...; done`, `keystroke` returning 0 when escape was hit, 1 (or more) otherwise.

Comment: @pawamoy Please read OP's question, example and come again to re-read my answer. When you're inside a function, `return` is perfectly fine and preferable way to *break* out early; does not matter whether the function has regular commands or loop within. `return` also sets the exit status of the function FYI (like I mentioned).

Comment: I've done that, and I still don't think you're answering OP's question. Your answer only tells about the `return` keyword and what it does.  OP wants to **break the parent loop** from within a function, not simply return early from a function.

Comment: @pawamoy How do I return a status code from a function that the caller of the function can check?

Comment: @heemayl With the return keyword, just like in your answer. That's what you want me to say right? Still, your answer is incomplete and therefore seems off the mark. Please dont take it personally. Your answer can be improved.

Comment: @pawamoy Don't worry, I'm not taking it personally :) If you feel you can contribute, you can always add an answer.

Comment: Sure, will do :)

Answer (score 7):

Indeed it seems that since Bash 4.4, the `break` keyword is not allowed anymore outside of a `for`, `while` or `until` loop.

I verified this with [`shenv`](https://github.com/shenv/shenv) and the following snippet. With Bash 4.3.30:

```
$ shenv shell bash-4.3.30
$ bash -c 'b() { break; }; for i in 1; do echo $i; b; done'
1
```

And with Bash 4.4:

```
$ shenv shell bash-4.4
$ bash -c 'b() { break; }; for i in 1; do echo $i; b; done'
1
environment: line 0: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

And the line in the changelog: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071/CHANGES#L677.

> xx. Fixed a bug that could allow `break' or`continue' executed from shell
>   functions to affect loops running outside of the function.

So now you cannot use the `break` keyword in a function anymore to break the parent loop. The solution is to return a status code instead, and check that code in the parent loop:

```
keystroke()
{
    read -s -n1 -t0.1 key
    [ "$key" = $'\e' ] &&
    {
        echo Aborted by user
        return 1
    }
}

while true; do
    ...
    keystroke || break
    ...
done
```

However, we can see in the changelog another interesting information:
https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071/CHANGES#L5954.

> i.  In POSIX mode, `break' and`continue' do not complain and return success
>   if called when the shell is not executing a loop.

So it seems you can retain the old behavior if you enable POSIX-mode.

```
$ shenv shell bash-4.4
$ bash --posix -c 'b() { break; }; for i in 1; do echo $i; b; done'
1
```